# Web API Model setter exception not being passed through

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception

I have an APIController and a class for input.

POST handler:

```
    public void Post([FromBody]NRCSSoilInput input)
    {
            new NRCSSoilWebService().SendRequest(input.box.west, input.box.north, input.box.east, input.box.south);
    }
```

Input class:

```
    public class NRCSSoilInput
    {
        public class BBox
        {
            public double north { get; set; }
            public double south { get; set; }
            public double east { get; set; }
            public double west { get; set; }
        }

        private BBox _box;
        public BBox box
        {
            get { return _box; }
            set { Validate(value); _box = value; }
        }

        public void Validate(BBox value)
        {
            if (value.west > value.east)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("west", value.west, "West cannot be bigger than east coordinate.");

            ... etc ...
        }
    }
```

So what's happening is that when an exception is hit, the object is not created (as expected), but the code continues and hits SendRequest in Post and then fails at input.box.west as input.box is null. And that's what the Post call returns to the frontend. What I want it to return though is the ArgumentOutOfRangeException, which I would have though would stop the code.

```
ExceptionMessage:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
ExceptionType:"System.NullReferenceException"
Message:"An error has occurred."
```

I guess an easy solution would be to move the validate into the Post, I'm not a fan of that idea though as in my mind the validation should happen when the Input object is created.

Got a couple of side questions:

- Another advantage of putting the validate into the Post is that I can put it into a try catch block and then return an OK response with { status: error, message : "error message" }, instead of a 500 response.
- the input json would have to have east, west, etc as integer, but it should really accept them as string and then convert them as well.

Are there any neat ways of doing the things above?

Comment: Did you check my answer ? Did I miss something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do is by Data Annotations (out of the box or FluentValidations) and Filter attributes see below.

Step 1 - Build a custom attribute. (I am using out of the box Data Annotations for this example)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DoubleGreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public DoubleGreaterThanAttribute(string doubleToCompareToFieldName)
    {
        DoubleToCompareToFieldName = doubleToCompareToFieldName;
    }

    private string DoubleToCompareToFieldName { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        double west = (double)value;

        double east = (double)validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(DoubleToCompareToFieldName).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (east > west)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("West cannot be bigger than east coordinate.");
        }
    }
}
```

Step -2 Annotate properties with custom attribute

```
public class NRCSSoilInput
{
    public class BBox
    {
        public double north { get; set; }
        public double south { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double east { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DoubleGreaterThan("east")]
        public double west { get; set; }
    }
    public BBox box { get; set; }
}
```

Step 3- Add a filter attribute class as below (preferably inside Filters folder)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true)]
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool> _validate;

    public ValidateModelAttribute()
        : this(arguments =>
            arguments.ContainsValue(null))
    { }

    public ValidateModelAttribute(Func<Dictionary<string, object>, bool> checkCondition)
    {
        _validate = checkCondition;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

        var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

        if (!modelState.IsValid)
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                 .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);

          }
}
```

Step 4 - On your controller annotate the filter attribute

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateModel]        
    public Void Post(NRCSSoilInput model)
    {
            return Ok();
    }
```

This way your method will be hit only when model passes all the validations. Hope this helps.